# How to put a scrollable gradient background at the bottom of an element?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a scrollable gradient background at the bottom of my `body`.

```css
/*Set Up*/

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav,
header,
main,
footer,
section,
article,
aside {
  display: block
}


/*Set Up*/

* {
  color: white;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #040d21, #040d21, #ffffff) no-repeat bottom;
  /*linear-gradient(to bottom right , #042d6b, #040d21, #040d21) no-repeat scroll*/
  /*url("../media/techgrid.png")*/
  background-color: #040d21;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  /*    461f48*/
}

header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: red solid;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
}

main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: red solid;
  width: 70%;
  position: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Mueller-UIs</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>This is a fresh website</h1>
    <p>This is a beautiful test paragraph.</p>
  </header>
  <main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
  </main>
  <footer>

  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

The result is a scrollable gradient at the top, although I put `background: bottom`:

[image]

[image]

The gradient can be put to the bottom by `background: fixed` but then it just gets fixated to the viewport.

How can I put it to the bottom of `body` so it stays there and make it scrollable?

Comment: Your html is set to height 100%, if you remove that then your body is set to 1000px high. Remove both then your bg will be at the bottom of body as you expected.

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thank you :-)

Comment: @Huangism for future questions, may I also ask how I can embed HTML into Stack Overflow? Was my formatting invalid?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov you can use the snippet feature on Stack overflow. Here's an image of how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PiY5.png . After you have entered your code you can press "Save & insert into post" and the snippet will automatically be inserted into your question/answer.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov it was not invalid, I just put it in a snippet so it is easier to access by others. Your chance of getting an answer increases when people can see the issue right away in a live example

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS code you have specified a height of 100% in the `html` area and a height of 1000px in the body area. If you remove these two, everything should work as you wanted it to.

This is what the code would look like:

```css
/*Set Up*/

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav,
header,
main,
footer,
section,
article,
aside {
  display: block
}


/*Set Up*/

* {
  color: white;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #040d21, #040d21, #ffffff) no-repeat bottom;
  /*linear-gradient(to bottom right , #042d6b, #040d21, #040d21) no-repeat scroll*/
  /*url("../media/techgrid.png")*/
  background-color: #040d21;
  background-size: 100%;
  /*    461f48*/
}

header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: red solid;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
}

main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: red solid;
  width: 70%;
  position: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Mueller-UIs</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>This is a fresh website</h1>
    <p>This is a beautiful test paragraph.</p>
  </header>
  <main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid est hic obcaecati, officiis quae recusandae sit! Accusamus ex maxime officiis pariatur quaerat. Adipisci impedit ipsum modi optio quis rerum voluptate?</p>
  </main>
  <footer>

  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```